# How can I get a value of a specific item using XPath?

Tags: selenium, gettext, getvalue

I want to compare the Outstanding balance amount with the database amount. How do I extract/get the amount to perform an assertion? Here I have given the screenshot of the outstanding amount. Using XPath how to get the amount 11,350.53?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.text` attribute of the `WebElement` returned by the XPath to get the string `$ 11,350.53`:

In Python:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='Outstanding Balance:']/following-sibling::div/p").text
print(text.strip())
```

In Java:

```
string text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Outstanding Balance:']/following-sibling::div/p")).getText();
System.out.println(text.trim());
```

The above XPath begins the query on the `label` element containing text `Outstanding Balance:`. The `label` element's `following-sibling` is `<div class='col-xs-5 text-right'>`. After locating this `div`, we query on its child element `p` which contains the text `$ 11,350.53`.